# Pointwise convergence and differentiability implies uniform convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

The problem:

True or False:
If $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ and $f_n\in C^1([a,b])$ and $f_n$ weakly converges in $(C([a,b]), \mid \mid \cdot \mid \mid_{\infty})$ to $f\in C([a,b])$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$; in other words $\mid \mid f_n-f_\infty\mid \mid_{\infty} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

I tried contradiction but it didn't lead anywhere $\ldots$ I looked at Dini's Theorem and I found another theorem which has this conclusion but assumes uniform convergence of $(f_n ')_n$, but I don't have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no and here is a counter example: let $f_n$ be the continuous function on $[0,1]$ whose graph is a poligonal line with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1/n,1)$, $(2/n,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  Then it is easy to see that $f_n\to0$ pointwise, but not uniformly.  By Riesz, any continuous functional $\phi$  on $C[0,1]$ is given by the integration against a complex measure with finite total variation, so $\phi(f_n)\to0$ by Lebesgue's dominated convergence Theorem.

If you want a sequence of smooth functions, it is enough to take smooth approximations of the above $f_n$.

Comment: Thank you! Nice argument. 
Also say, we would have $f_n$ weakly converging to $f$ in $C^1([0,1])$ instead. 
Can we conclude that $f_n$ strongly converges to $f$ in $C([0,1])$?